# Flutter conditionnal import mobile vs desktop

Tags: flutter, import, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop

Importing on web vs native is easy

```dart
import '../wrappers/platform/platform_none.dart'
    if (dart.library.io) '../wrappers/platform/platform_io.dart'
    if (dart.library.js) '../wrappers/platform/platform_web.dart';
```

What if I want to import a different package depending on whether I am on mobile (iOS/Android) vs on desktop (Linux/MacOS/Windows)?

If there is no way with conditional import, how can you achieve that any other way?

Comment: What specific packages are you using that you would want to exclude between Mobile and Desktop?

Comment: move_to_background, to put an app in the background. Of course this does not make sense with desktop so it's no supported.

Comment: But is it causing you issues, or are you simply preoccupied with App size?

Comment: Issue, I am developing a cross platform plug-in so sacrificing 3 platform because of conditional import is such a bummer.. I did find a workaround but it basically meant duplicating all the source files of the plug-in I was using, but of course this is not a real solution.

Comment: The native code of a plugin is only compiled for the specific platform it applies to. Only the Dart code would be included everywhere, and the plugin you mentioned above has only a single 16-line Dart file, including whitespace and comments. The difference between excluding it or not is negligible.

Comment: The size is not the issue. This issue is that, if I include this plug-in in mine, mine will loose the desktops badges on pub.dev since move_to_background only supports mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do what you are describing; conditional imports [only support library-based conditions](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34262#issuecomment-416129832), and there is no difference in supported libraries for mobile and desktop.

Comment: Theorically the dart team could create dummy libraries that would serve this purpose then.

Comment: Anyway sorry for not accepting earlier after much research you are right it cannot be done with the shipped libraries. I still think it's a pain but anyway ;)

Comment: @Lulupointu have you found a workaround to this?

Comment: @ValentinVignal As I said in one of the comment, one solution for me (having only an Android version of the plugin) was to create a dummy version of the class I needed manually (which only returns error) and then use conditional import. That's not the best but at least it work if you really need to, no matter how tedious